# Angular JWT interceptor switch bearer token for refresh

Tags: angular, jwt

I have implemented a JWT and refresh token flow. When I implemented this in the past, I did it a bit differently, mainly that the refresh token was sent in the body.

But now I've done it differently, and I have to send the access token via the Authorization header, but my interceptor code doesn't want to switch out the bearer token. How do I fix, that if I'm wanting to refresh, I actually use the refresh token as the bearer token instead of the access token that has expired?

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.userService.getJWTToken();
    if (token) {
      request = this.addToken(request, token);
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next);
        } else if (error.status !== 0) {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      })
    );
  }

private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
  }

  private handle401Error(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      //This is what I've tried, to switch out the tokens
      request = this.addToken(request, this.userService.getRefreshToken());

      //this.userService.refreshToken() is a POST request, where I want the refresh token as the bearer token, instead of the access token
      return this.userService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: TokenDTO) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.accessToken);
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.accessToken));
        })
      );
    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter((token) => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((accessToken) =>
          next.handle(this.addToken(request, accessToken))
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

I have also tried setting the HTTP header to the authorization bearer token, in the post request

```
public refreshToken(): Observable<TokenDTO> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getRefreshToken()}`,
    });

    return this.httpClient
      .post<TokenDTO>(`${this.hostname}/users/refreshToken`, {}, headers)
      .pipe(
        tap((tokens: TokenDTO) => {
          this.saveTokens(tokens);
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not replace the access token with the bearer token to refresh it, instead you call the dedicated token endpoint with your refresh token to get a new access token. Sometimes, depending on the setup, you might get back a new refresh token as well.

Comment: Well that is exactly what I’m trying to do, maybe i worded it badly. I’m tying to use the refresh token to make a request to the refresh token endpoint, from where I get a new access token and a new refresh token. Then i save the new access token and use that. Or are you saying the implementation in my previous projects, where i added the refresh token in the body was correct?

Comment: it was a bit difficult to understand exactly what the question is :-) I meant your past project sounded a bit wrong. The refresh token should not be sent as an authorization header in the request and it should not be sent to any other service than the idp.

Comment: So, what would be the best way to actually send and refresh the token?

Comment: A popular option nowdays is to use the BFF pattern to manage the tokens, this also gives you better security than trying to manage tokens in Angular. https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the refresh token in the `Authorization` header. This means that you should not authorize the request based only on the value of the refresh token. If you do that then anyone who steals the refresh token will be able to use it to get a new access token! The refresh token is the data needed to issue new tokens, but you should authorize the client (your app) in another way. E.g. you can use HTTP Basic authentication and pass the client's ID and secret, or use more sophisticated stuff, like mutual TLS.